# Identifying trends over time (Java)

Tags: java, twitter

I am building an application that tracks hashtags on Twitter.

Every time a tweet is posted for a hashtag that I am watching, my application adds the tweet's timestamp in an `ArrayList<Long>` and logs it into a CSV file.

I am trying to figure out a way to determine when one of the hashtags I am following "blows up," so I can send an alert. How can I do this?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I don't think there's a standard, canonical answer. You can use a lot of different techniques here.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's java question. I'd say it's about data mining, statistics etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything about your application, I'd say that what you want to do is track the `rate` of each particular hashtag, or usage over time. What I would do is whenever a hashtag is logged, you would increment its value in a `HashMap`. (Hehe, HashTag, HashMap? No? Okay...) If the hashtag's value goes beyond a certain threshold, you send an alert. Every minute or hour or day, whatever you choose, you would reset the whole `HashMap`.

Something like this:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> tagrate = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public final int THRESHOLD = 10000; //is ten thousand tags in one hour a lot? I don't use twitter...

public void logHashTag(String name){
    log(name); //your original logging mechanism
    int current = tagrate.get(name);
    tagrate.put(name, current + 1); //increment
    if (current > THRESHOLD){
        alert(name);
    }
}
public void resetTable(){ //call this every hour (or minute or whatever)
    tagrate = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}
```

For choosing the time period, it's up to you. A smaller time period would be more specific, but a larger time period would be probably better for performance. For example, if you reset the table every second, it would be pretty bad for your application.